# PL/SQL - Get the most recent month and total sales amount

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Suppose you have this table structure:

[image]

How can i query this data in order to give the most recent month (4) and the total sales amount (11000)?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a coding service. What did you try ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you just want the most recent month use simple max

```
-- this should return 4 and 11000
select max(month),sum(total_sales) from table1;
```

If you have other columns in the table then those can be included (eg. total_sales for this year ...)

Answer (score 2):

A simple `max` + `sum` will do:

```
select max(month),
       sum(total_sales)
  from table_name
```